# Most efficient way to find every max number in a set of a numbers

Tags: c#, max

I have 3 int values:

```
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;
```

And 3 bool values:

```
bool maxIs1;
bool maxIs2;
bool maxIs3;
```

Input values have to be separate variables.

`maxIs1 = True` means that `value1` must have maximum value and so on.

I need method to compare this set of numbers with set of conditions. 
For example:

```
int value1 = 10;
int value2 = 1;
int value3 = 10;

bool maxIs1 = True;
bool maxIs2 = False;
bool maxIs3 = True;

bool result = compareValues(); //true
```

Or:

```
int value1 = 1;
int value2 = 1;
int value3 = 10;

bool maxIs1 = True;
bool maxIs2 = False;
bool maxIs3 = True;

bool result = compareValues(); //false
```

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Is the amount of variables constant (3) or there might be additional variables?

Comment: In my case here is only 3.

Comment: If you *are* worried about efficience and more than 3 values, this is an `O(n)` problem and you should only have to iterate the input once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to care about efficiency in case of 3 values

```
int value1 = 10;
int value2 = 1;
int value3 = 1;

bool maxIs1 = true;
bool maxIs2 = false;
bool maxIs3 = true;

int max = new[] { value1, value2, value3 }.Max();
bool result = (!maxIs1 || value1 == max) && (!maxIs2 || value2 == max) && (!maxIs3 || value3 == max);
```

Answer (score 2):

This was fun. If you can put them into an array you can use linq to cleanly check if they all satisfy the condition:

```
var values = new[] { value1, value2, value3 };
var maxes = new[] { maxIs1, maxIs2, maxIs3 };
var max = values.Max();

var result = values
    .Zip(maxes, (f, s) => new { value = f, isMax = s })
    .All(c => !c.isMax || (c.value == max));
```

Comment: Does your answer satisfy the condition if value is maximum but the bool value says that it is not, I think in this case it should return false

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh: if that's the desired behavior you can change the last line to `.All(c => (!c.isMax && c.value != max) || (c.isMax && c.value == max));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you want different number of value :

```
static void Main()
    {
        List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
        List<bool> listOfBools = new List<bool>();

        listOfInts.Add(1);
        listOfInts.Add(2);
        listOfInts.Add(1);

        listOfBools.Add(false);
        listOfBools.Add(false);
        listOfBools.Add(false);

        Console.WriteLine("value = " + Compare(listOfInts,listOfBools));

    }
```

and `Compare()` should be like this :

```
static bool Compare(List<int> listOfInts, List<bool> listOfBools)
    {
        int max = listOfInts.Max();
        bool isCorrect = true;

        var maxList = listOfInts.Where(value => value == max);
        var indicesOfMax = GetIndeciesOfMax(maxList, listOfInts);

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfInts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (indicesOfMax.Contains(i) && listOfInts[i] == max && listOfBools[i])
            {
                isCorrect = true;
            }
            else if (!indicesOfMax.Contains(i) && listOfInts[i] != max && !listOfBools[i])
            {
                isCorrect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isCorrect = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isCorrect;
    }

    static List<int> GetIndeciesOfMax(IEnumerable<int> maxList, List<int> list)
    {
        List<int> indecies = new List<int>();

        foreach (var m in maxList)
        {
            indecies.Add(list.IndexOf(m));
        }

        return indecies;
    }
```